# A python code issue (About lexeme)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am programming a python project, then I have some problems that I can not run my program. The following code is my program that about a lexical analyzer:(And this program I have refered to other guys online to write it)

```
> import re
> 
> token_pattern = r"""
> 
> (?P<IDENTIFIER> [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)
> 
> | (?P<INT_LITERAL> [0-9]+)
> 
> | (?P<SEMICOLON>\;)
> 
> | (?P<LIFT_PARENTHESIS>[(])
> 
> | (?P<RIGT_PARENTHESIS>[)])
> 
> | (?P<ASSIGN_OP>[=])
> 
> | (?P<ADD_OP>[+])
> 
> | (?P<SUB_OP>[=])
> 
> | (?P<DIV_OP>[/])
> 
> | (?P<MUL_OP>[*])
> 
> | (?P<LT_OP>[<])
> 
> | (?P<GT_OP>[>])
> 
> | (?P<LTE_OP>[<=])
> 
> | (?P<GTE_OP>[>=])
> 
> | (?P<EQ_OP>[==])
> 
> | (?P<NEQ_OP>[!=])
> 
> | (?P<LEFT_BRACE>[{])
> 
> | (?P<RIGHT_BRACE>[}]
> 
> | (?P<LEFT_BRACKET>[[])
> 
> | (?P<RIGHT_BRACKET>[]])
> 
> | (?P<OR_OP>[||])
> 
> | (?P<AND_OP>[&&]) """
> 
> token_re = re.compile(token_pattern, re.VERBOSE) /"I dont know what
> this line means. "/
> 
> class TokenizerException(Exception):pass
> 
> def tokenize(text):

pos =0

while True:

    m = token_re.match(text, pos)
    if not m:break
    pos = m.end()
    tokname=m.lastgroup
    tokvalue=m.group(tokname)
    yield tokname, tokvalue
if pos != len(text):
    raise TokenizerException('tokenizer stopped at pos %r of %r' % ( pos, len(text)))


stuff = r'property.{general.name}.ip=)'


print ('stuff'.center(60, '='))

for tok in tokenize(stuff):
    print (tok)
```

When I run the program, it displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/project2.py", line 28, in <module>
    token_re = re.compile(token_pattern, re.VERBOSE)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 214, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 283, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_compile.py", line 491, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_parse.py", line 747, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_parse.py", line 359, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))

  File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_parse.py", line 697, in _parse
    raise error("unbalanced parenthesis")
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

How to run it exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You must decompose your pattern to identify where the problem lies.  A simple mechanism is to bisect the pattern and continue with this until you identify the offending portion.

The regular expression engine complains that you have unbalanced parens.

It's likely coming from the patterns searching for parens:

```
(?P<LIFT_PARENTHESIS>[(])
```

"`LIFT`" and "`RIGT`" parens should escape the paren itself since it's significant.

Instead use:

```
(?P<LIFT_PARENTHESIS>[\(])
```